# How do I graph a transformed rational function?

Tags: rational-functions

If the function is $-\frac{5}{x+3} + 2$ how would I graph that without using a table of values? Do I just use the asymptotes $x=-3$, and $y= 2$ and draw the general shape? Do I use "mapping points" like $(x-3, -5y+2)$?

Comment: The asymptote would be $x=-3$, not $x=3$

Comment: Woops, ok, x=-3. Now what?

Answer (score 2):

One way to graph the function
$$f(x) = -\frac{5}{x + 3} + 2$$
is to apply the series of transformations 
$$\frac{1}{x} \to -\frac{1}{x} \to -\frac{5}{x} \to -\frac{5}{x + 3} \to -\frac{5}{x + 3} + 2$$
We start with the graph of $y = 1/x$.  The $x$- and $y$-axes are, respectively, the horizontal and vertical asymptotes of the graph.

[image: graph_of_reciprocal_function]

We can obtain the graph of $y = -1/x$ from the graph of $y = 1/x$ by reflecting the graph in the $x$-axis.

[image: graph_of_reflected_reciprocal_function]

We can obtain the graph of $y = -5/x$ from the graph of $y = -1/x$ by stretching the graph of $y = -1/x$ vertically by a factor of $5$.

[image: graph_of_reflected_and_stretched_reciprocal_function]

We can obtain the graph of $y = -5/(x + 3)$ from the graph of $y = -5/x$ by shifting the graph of $y = -5/x$ to the left by three units.  The vertical line $x = -3$ that is shown in red is the translated vertical asymptote.

[image: graph_of_reflected_stretched_and_translated_reciprocal_function]

Finally, we can obtain the graph of the function 
$$f(x) = -\frac{5}{x + 3} + 2$$
from the graph of $y = -5/(x + 3)$ by translating the graph of $y = -5/(x + 3)$ upwards by two units.  The horizontal line $y = 2$ is the translated horizontal asymptote.  The vertical line $x = 3$ is the vertical asymptote.

[image: graph_of_rational_function_showing_asymptotic_behavior]

I opted to use a larger graph for the final function in order to illustrate its asymptotic behavior.

**Alternate Method:**  We solve for the intercepts and asymptotes, then perform a line analysis.

$x$*-intercept:*  Setting $f(x) = 0$ yields
\begin{align*}
-\frac{5}{x + 3} + 2 & = 0\\
2 & = \frac{5}{x + 3}\\
2x + 6 & = 5\\
2x & = -1\\
x & = -\frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

$y$*-intercept:*  Evaluating the function at $x = 0$ yields
\begin{align*}
f(0) & = -\frac{5}{0 + 3} + 2\\
     & = -\frac{5}{3} + \frac{6}{3}\\
     & = \frac{1}{3}
\end{align*}

*horizontal asymptote:*  As $|x| \to \infty$, the term 
$$-\frac{5}{x + 3} \to 0$$ 
so 
$$y = -\frac{5}{x + 3} + 2 \to 2$$
the horizontal asymptote is the line $y = 2$.

*vertical asymptote:*  Since the denominator of 
$$f(x) = -\frac{5}{x + 3} + 2 = -\frac{5}{x + 3} + \frac{2x + 6}{x + 3} = \frac{2x + 1}{x + 3}$$
vanishes at $x = 3$ and the numerator does not, $x = -3$ is the vertical asymptote of the function's graph.

*line analysis:*  The function can only change sign at an $x$-intercept or a vertical asymptote.  Therefore, its sign is constant in the intervals $(-\infty, -3)$, $(-3, 1/2)$, and $(1/2, \infty)$.  The function is equal to $0$ at the $x$-intercept $1/2$ and undefined at $x = 3$ since it has a vertical asymptote there.  Expressing the function in the form 
$$f(x) = \frac{2x + 1}{x + 3}$$
we see that its sign is the product of the signs of the dividend $2x + 1$ and divisor $x + 3$.  The divisor is negative when $x < -3$, $0$ at $x = -3$, and positive when $x > 3$.  The dividend is negative when $x < -1/2$, $0$ at $x = -1/2$, and positive when $x > 1/2$.  Hence, the quotient is positive when $x < 3$, undefined at $x = -3$, negative when $-3 < x < -1/2$, zero at $x = -1/2$, and positive when $x > 1/2$.

[image: line_analysis]

Thus, when $x < -3$, we draw the curve in the region above the horizontal asymptote $y = 2$, and when $x > -3$, we draw the curve in the region below the horizontal asymptote so that it passes through the $x$- and $y$-intercepts, as shown above.

Comment: How do you stretch the graph by a factor of 5? Do you multiply every y-value by 5?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: I have added an alternate approach that is more useful for more complicated rational functions.